# DynamoDB equivelent to Find({}).toArray

Tags: node.js, mongodb, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I'm looking to export an entire table in DynamoDB as an array of objects. I'm recently converting from MongoDB, and in that I'd use .find({}).toArray( (err,res)=> {...} ). I'm having a bit of trouble finding an alternative to DynamoDB.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Scan](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Scan.html).

> The Scan operation returns one or more items and item attributes by
>   accessing every item in a table or a secondary index. To have DynamoDB
>   return fewer items, you can provide a FilterExpression operation.

The data from the **Scan** operation is returned in JSON format, which has an **Items** element:

> **Items**
>
> An array of item attributes that match the scan criteria. Each element
>   in this array consists of an attribute name and the value for that
>   attribute.
>
> Type: array of String to [AttributeValue](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_AttributeValue.html) object maps